# How to troubleshoot "Unable to cast object of type 'System.String'" in CallBimlScript

Tags: c#, biml

I have a BIML solution that calls several .biml files through three tiers using BimlScript. I'm passing an AstConnectionNode parameter in the CallBimlScript(). However, when I call it using an AstConnectionNode parameter, I receive the error message "Unable to cast object of type 'System.String' to type 'Varigence.Languages.Biml.Connection.AstOleDbConnectionNode'."

1. The parameter name is connectionWrk. I initialize the parameter as a connection node in the first tier:

   ```
   <# var connStrWrk = "Data Source=SomeServer;Initial Catalog=SomeDatabase;Provider=SQLNCLI11.1;Integrated Security=SSPI;Auto Translate=False;"; #>
   <# var connectionWrk = SchemaManager.CreateConnectionNode("SchemaProvider", connStrWrk); #>
   ```
2. Then I pass it as a parameter in a CallBimlScript method from the first tier:

   ```
   <#=CallBimlScript("01.01.02.GenStg_STD_FullLoad.biml", table, columnList, tableNorm, connectionWrk) #>
   ```
3. It's mapped to the callee's parameters in the second tier "01.01.02.GenStg_STD_FullLoad.biml":

   ```
   <#@ import namespace="System.Data" #> 

   <#@ property name="table" type="Varigence.Languages.Biml.Table.AstTableNode" #>
   <#@ property name="columnList" type="String" #>
   <#@ property name="tableNorm" type="String" #>
   <#@ property name="connectionWrk" type="Varigence.Languages.Biml.Connection.AstOleDbConnectionNode" #>
   ```
4. Then I use it again as a parameter in a CallBimlScript() from the second tier:

   ```
   <#=CallBimlScript("01.01.01.a.x.SourceFromClause.biml", hashTable, tableNorm, LoadType, connectionWrk) #>
   ```
5. And it's mapped to the callee in third tier:

   ```
   <#@ import namespace="System.Data" #>

   <#@ property name="hashTable" type="Varigence.Languages.Biml.Table.AstTableNode" required="False"#>
   <#@ property name="tableNorm" type="String" required="True"#>
   <#@ property name="LoadType" type="String" required="True"#>
   <#@ property name="connectionWrk" type="Varigence.Languages.Biml.Connection.AstOleDbConnectionNode" required="True" #>`
   ```
6. Then I use it to get metadata in a SQL Server database:

   ```
   <#
   var JoinLogic = ExternalDataAccess.GetDataTable(connectionWrk.ConnectionString, 
                                            "SELECT [TABLE_NAME_SRC], [FROM_TABLE], [RANK], " +
                                            "[JOIN_TYPE], [JOIN_TABLE], [JOIN_KEY], [WHERE_CLAUSE] " +
                                            "FROM [PHDDV_VMC_WORK].[ETL_WORK].[VMC_STG_FROM_WHERE_CLS] " +
                                            "WHERE [TABLE_NAME_SRC] = '" + tableNorm + "' " + 
                                            "AND [FROM_TABLE] != '" + tableNorm + "' " + 
                                            "ORDER BY [RANK]; "
                                            ).Rows.OfType<DataRow>().Select(r => new[]
                                                                                     {
                                                                                      r["TABLE_NAME_SRC"].ToString(),
                                                                                      r["FROM_TABLE"].ToString(),
                                                                                      r["RANK"].ToString(),
                                                                                      r["JOIN_TYPE"].ToString(),
                                                                                      r["JOIN_TABLE"].ToString(),
                                                                                      r["JOIN_KEY"].ToString(),
                                                                                      r["WHERE_CLAUSE"].ToString()
                                                                                     });
   #>
   ```

As far I can tell, it has the type of Varigence.Languages.Biml.Connection.AstOleDbConnectionNode in all three tiers.

Using a parameter through multiple tiers has worked for me in prior BIML solutions, but this time I'm stumped as to how to get this parameter to be interpreted as AstOleDbConnectionNode in all three tiers.

Why would it be interpreted as a String type and what could I do to solve this or troubleshoot it?

I need to be able to use this connection node parameter in modular code for reusing the logic in multiple BIML files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Drop the required true/false from the third tier/step 5 (or change up your invocation order). I'll have go dig up notes but I *think* I recall it affecting the order of parameters. Logically, it makes sense - you'd have to supply your required parameters first and then list your optional parameters.

I ginned up a quick repro and you can verify the behaviour by making 4 look like

```
<#=CallBimlScript(child, columnList, tableNorm, connectionWrk, table) #>
```

(or however you've modified values in the second tier)

My repro

### Tier 1 code

```
<Biml xmlns="http://schemas.varigence.com/biml.xsd">
<# var connStrWrk = @"Data Source=.\dev2017;Initial Catalog=tempdb;Provider=SQLNCLI11.1;Integrated Security=SSPI;Auto Translate=False;"; #>
<# var connectionWrk = SchemaManager.CreateConnectionNode("SchemaProvider", connStrWrk); #> 
<# string child = "so_54450877.tier2.biml" ;
   Varigence.Languages.Biml.Table.AstTableNode table = new Varigence.Languages.Biml.Table.AstTableNode(null);
   table.Name = "tablename";
   string columnList = "column,list";
   string tableNorm = "tablenormname";
   #>
<#=CallBimlScript(child, table, columnList, tableNorm, connectionWrk) #>
</Biml>
```

### Tier 2 code

```
<#@ import namespace="System.Data" #> 

<#@ property name="table" type="Varigence.Languages.Biml.Table.AstTableNode" #>
<#@ property name="columnList" type="String" #>
<#@ property name="tableNorm" type="String" #>
<#@ property name="connectionWrk" type="Varigence.Languages.Biml.Connection.AstOleDbConnectionNode" #>
<!-- Tier 2 debug -->
<# string child = "so_54450877.tier3.biml" ;
var results = ExternalDataAccess.GetDataTable(connectionWrk,"SELECT 'This is tier 2' AS TierName;") ;
foreach (System.Data.DataRow row in results.Rows)
{
    for (int columnIndex = 0; columnIndex < results.Columns.Count; columnIndex++)
    {
        Write(string.Format("<!-- {0} -->\t", row[columnIndex]));
    }

    Write("\n");
}

#>
<#=CallBimlScript(child, columnList, tableNorm, connectionWrk, table) #>
<!-- Tier 2 end debug -->
```

### Tier 3 code

```
<#@ import namespace="System.Data" #>

<#@ property name="hashTable" type="Varigence.Languages.Biml.Table.AstTableNode" required="False"#>
<#@ property name="tableNorm" type="String" required="True"#>
<#@ property name="LoadType" type="String" required="True"#>
<#@ property name="connectionWrk" type="Varigence.Languages.Biml.Connection.AstOleDbConnectionNode" required="True" #>
<!-- I exist -->
<# 
string connstring = connectionWrk.ConnectionString;
var results = ExternalDataAccess.GetDataTable(connectionWrk,"SELECT 'This is tier 3' AS TierName;") ;

foreach (System.Data.DataRow row in results.Rows)
{
    for (int columnIndex = 0; columnIndex < results.Columns.Count; columnIndex++)
    {
        Write(string.Format("!<-- {0} -->\t", row[columnIndex]));
    }

    Write("\n");
}
#>
```

Results

[image: Debug output]

Comment: It was all about the order of parameters. Caller order has to match the callee order.

Comment: Thanks! all my packages genned up now!